# Compare the time duration of two movies

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, boolean

I am going to make a function that takes starting timing of two movies: `hr1,hr2,min1,min2`, and their durations, `durmin1,durmin2` and decides whether we can binge and watch both movies.

The criteria are that they must not overlap and that we are not going to wait more than 30 minutes between the end of one and the beginning of the next. It returns true if the criteria are both met and returns false otherwise. Movie start times are always after 1 pm and before midnight. The first one always starts earlier. The order of the input arguments is: `hr1, min1, durmin1, hr2, min2, durmin2`

I am unable to understand what will my function will do. What are these timing `hr1,hr2`? Why duration has been given?

I have tried this:

```
function mymovies=movies(hr1,min1,dur1,hr2,min2) 
h1=hr1+min/60+dur1; 
h2=hr2+min/60; 

    if h2-h1>=30/60 && h2-h1~=0 
        disp('Ture') 

    else 
        disp('False') 
    end 

end
```

Comment: function mymovies=movies(hr1,min1,dur1,hr2,min2)
h1=hr1+min/60+dur1;
h2=hr2+min/60;
if h2-h1>=30/60 && h2-h1~=0
disp('Ture')
else
    disp('False')
end
end

Comment: when i run these codes i getting an error..check whether i am doing correct which the question ask from me or not. If i am doing correction guide me where i need corrections.Thanks in advance for assistance

Comment: I have edited your code into your question. If you are getting an error, you should press `edit`, above, and add the error.  I suspect this is just typos, though - `min` is a function that finds the minimum, not one of your variables. Check your code carefully, and use the inbuilt debugger tools.

Comment: thanks @nkjt for editing my post..... i really want this but i do not know how format in this manner

Answer (score 1):

well, with proper variables and a little thinking just one if is sufficient to solve this problem.As far as I have understood, you definitely do not need to consider the duration for the second movie. you only need to worry about the details of the first movie and the start time of the second movie. You also need to "return" the boolean result not display it. So here is what you should do, given the instructions in your question:

First: Convert the total time from when movie one starts till it ends to minutes

Second: convert the total start time of movie two to minutes

Finally, just use the difference to meet the conditions given in the instructions in a simpe if statement. Try that with your grader then let me know what happens then. (preferably of movie2 - movie1) since you are free to assume that movie1 will always start first)
Given your level, this should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

-step 1: convert hr, min to only minutes (past 1pm if you want...)
so:

```
start_movie_1 = hr1*60 + min1
end_movie_1 = start_movie_1 + durmin1
```

Similar for movie 2.

-step 2: find if they overlap.

```
if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 and end_movie_1 > end_movie_2 => there is overlapping (whole movie 2 is inside movie 1)

if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 and end_movie_1 > start_movie_2 => there is overlapping (movie 2 will start before movie 1 finish)

if start_movie_2 < start_movie_1 and end_movie_2 > end_movie_1 => there is overlapping (whole movie 1 is inside movie 2)

if start_movie_2 < start_movie_1 and end_movie_2 > start_movie_1 => there is overlapping (movie 1 will start before movie 2 finish)
```

-step 3: now we know they don't overlap, so we need to check the time inbetween

```
if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 => return (start_movie_2 - end_movie_1) <= 30
else (start_movie_2 < start_movie_1)
return (start_movie_1 - end_movie_2) <= 30
```

---

Edited for an **even more simple** answer

```
function mymovies=movies(hr1,min1,dur1,hr2,min2,dur2) 
    start_movie_1 = hr1*60 + min1;
    end_movie_1 = start_movie_1 + dur1;
    start_movie_2 = hr2*60 + min2;
    end_movie_2 = start_movie_2 + dur2;

    if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 && end_movie_1 > end_movie_2
        disp('FALSE');
    else if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 && end_movie_1 > start_movie_2
        disp('FALSE');
    else if start_movie_2 < start_movie_1 && end_movie_2 > end_movie_1
        disp('FALSE');
    else if start_movie_2 < start_movie_1 && end_movie_2 > start_movie_1
        disp('FALSE');
    else 
        if start_movie_1 < start_movie_2 && (start_movie_2 - end_movie_1) <= 30
            disp('TRUE');
        else if (start_movie_2 < start_movie_1) && (start_movie_1 - end_movie_2) <= 30
            disp('TRUE');
        else
            disp('FALSE');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: i getting more confusion after your answer.Please answer me in simple logic.Thanks @Ignasi

Comment: thanks @lgnasi for contributions...  When i run grader which check my solution of programm i got an error :                                                Problem 6 (movies):
    Feedback: Your program made an error for argument(s) 1, 30, 120, 3, 45, 90

Comment: Actually question is asking from us logical true or false not of  disp('Ture or False') . How can this if statements can be converted to logical statements so that we get logical true or false.. thanks in advance

Comment: **mymovies = true** and **mymovies = false** will do the trick, but I think you should understand syntax before trying to solve **ANY** problem.